# Launchy "Rebuild Index" shortcut

Tags: launchy

Is there a keyboard shortcut for "Rebuild Index" command in Launchy 1.25 for Windows XP? If there isn't it would be quite ironic :}

Comment: Just FYI, the latest version is 2.1.2, and it was released like 1.5 years ago, so you might want to update.

Comment: And there's a beta of version 2.5 if you look hard enough. But yeah, no need to still use v1.25.

Answer (score 4):

Just press `F5` in Launchy 2.5 to rescan the catalog.

---

Alternatively, if you *really, really* want a shortcut, create a shortcut with a target of:

```
"C:\Program Files\Launchy\Launchy.exe" -rescan
```

And put it in some folder that is in the Launchy catalog.

---

Just be sure to read the manual from now on. It does say:

> ### Launchy 2.5
>
> ## PLEASE READ THIS!